# I want to pass a dynamic expression into a switch activity from a pipeline parameter using the output of a Get Metadata activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

https://app.screencast.com/fumwjEC5FYXH9 - this 3 min video is more effective than text.

Summary: I have a pipeline that I use to check a blob storage file to make sure it includes certain columns before executing some downstream activity. This pipeline would be called by other ETL pipelines to determine if the latter proceed.

I have it working with the switch activity expression being hardcoded. What I want to be able to do is re-define the switch activity expression as a pipeline parameter so that I can call this for any kind of file/looking for any kind of get metadata criteria.

In the video I show the working example and discuss a few things I've tried. I'm missing something fundamental, I'm generally not getting errors from data factory so it is difficult to troubleshoot. I believe my problem is that it's just reading it as a string and not actually trying to evaluate the expression.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are following , that is , to parameterize the expression in switch activity is not feasible . The reason behind it is in pipeline parameter value, we do not have an option to write dynamic expression.It's basically a static value.

Although, `@pipeline().parameters.condition` would be replaced by the following expression: `@string(and(contains(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.structure),'Col1'),contains(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.structure),'Col2'))` , however, it won't be able to evaluate the same.

In dataflow activity, we have the option to pass the parameter as string or expression . But same is not the case with other activities.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I rarely use dataflows but this is worth a try, which I will do soon and then respond back here.

Comment: What data flow activity could be used to do the column name check? I'm not figuring that part out. Assert's are only for checking rows/values.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @[AnnuKumari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17721124/annukumari) that the above will result your dynamic expression as string instead of the value of the expression.

Currently, parameters in ADF won't support dynamic content but ADF variables supports dynamic content in default values.

But here, we cannot give the dynamic expression involving any ADF variables, activity outputs or pipeline parameters. It evaluates the dynamic expression which involves only the dynamic content functions.

**Sample demonstration:**

Here to see the value of `var1`, I have assigned variable `var1` to `res` in a set variable activity.

[image]

And you can see it got error saying that variable `use` cannot found.

[image]

> What I want to be able to do is re-define the switch activity expression as a pipeline parameter so that I can call this for any kind of file/looking for any kind of get metadata criteria

You cannot achieve this using pipeline parameters. If you want to re use the expression, **just store the expression result in a variable using set variable activity after respective activity**. You can use this variable wherever you want after this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure this helps me do what I ultimately want to do. I want to have this pipeline be something I call in other places, like a function. If I have to edit the expression in the Set Variable activity, that seems to leave me in the same place as editing the expression in the Switch.
Do you agree? Or perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes, I got your point. you want to store the expression in a constant and wants to use that constant whenever you required. But currently, it is not supported in ADF parameters. Even through dataflow parameters supports that behavior, you can access those values only inside the dataflow not inside the switch activity. I suggested the variables approach to avoid re-using of the whole expression and for simple usage but yes, I agree with you its same as editing the expression in switch activity.